# Sorting a list of strings by the length of first word

Tags: haskell

I am trying to Sort a list of Strings by the length of the first word in the strings (if the strings have more than one word) and return a list with the sorted strings. This is the code I have but is giving me errors. Can someone help me, please?

```
listStrings :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
listStrings  =  map (\ws -> (head ws , length ws)). group.sort.words
```

Comment: `words` has type `String -> [String]`, but you try apply it to `[String]`.

Comment: The second, your function `listStrings` has type `[String] -> [(String, Int)]`, but from your question the type should be `[String] -> [String]`. So what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Just make it compare the lenth of the first words on it

```
import Data.List

listStrings :: [String] -> [String]
listStrings = reverse . sortBy sortF 
    where
        sortF :: String -> String -> Ordering
        sortF = comparing (length . head . words)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/N48Z/2)

Comment: You may want to use `Data.Function`'s `on` instead of repeating `length . head . words` twice.

Comment: Or `sortF = comparing (length . head . words)`. Still, it is a bit inefficient to recompute that length at every comparison. Also, I'd handle the empty string, which currently triggers a `head` crash.

Comment: More efficient and correct will be `listStrings = sortOn (maybe 0 length . listToMaybe . words)`.